# How to edit a modal popup on woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, popup, modal-dialog

A developper created javascript modal popups in my woocommerce product page. I'd like to know how can I edit it or even delete it. I searched around in different forums and wasn't able to find a step by step answer.

That would be highly appreciated if you can explain me how can I make these changes.

Thanks you

Comment: as from hearing I would suggest to look into your javascript source and search around forsth that looks like a dynamically created popup. maybe contact developer for further information.

Comment: That's why I came here :) 
My developper disappeared and I need to make these changes. What I'm looking for is that someone can just tell me where to look

Comment: kindly, if you don't provide at list a link to that product page, nobody is going to help you! What theme are you using? Is there additional plugins related to lightbox, galleries, modal... Please update your question with much more details…

Comment: Thanks you

Please see in this product page: http://greenserp.com/produit/broche-boule-1/ (Password access: Tzuri246)
I'd like to edit "Tableau des tailles" and "Libraison grapuite". I see that the developper created 2 pages for each. I'm using the premium wordpress theme The7

Comment: Even with the link I don't think there's anyway to tell how the other developer may have built it. I'd check your theme's `functions.php` as that's a common place to have added those links. Otherwise, I think you might need to hire a new developer to take a look.